# Redux observable retry does not resend the API call

Tags: redux, react-redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am using redux-observable and want to retry 3 times whenever an API call throws error.

But it doesn't retry, it has only one http request sent.

I made up a sample calling github user api to find a user, if you provide a non exist username like `This doesn't exist` then it will throw an 404 error. I have added `retry(3)` but it doesn't retry.

You can find the codes on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwinyyycredux-observable-retry-forked-1jnxr)

```
export const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCH_USER),
  mergeMap(action =>
    ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${action.payload}`).pipe(
      map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
    )
  ),
  retry(3)
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your retry up into the inner observable, like so:

```js
export const fetchUserEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(FETCH_USER),
  mergeMap(action =>
    ajax.getJSON(`https://api.github.com/users/${action.payload}`).pipe(
      map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response)),
      retry(3)
    )
  )
);
```

Your `action$` doesn't actually fail, it's the ajax-call you want to retry.